# PostgreSQL query to find a particular pattern in a text column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, regexp-like

I have a `text` column in my database table which contains values like

```
A/B

A/B/C

A/B/C/D

A/B/C/D/E
```

Now, I want to select only those rows where this column value contains maximum three occurrences of `'/'`.
For clarity - expected output should be:

```
A/B

A/B/C

A/B/C/D
```

Can anyone help me with such a query?

Comment: Please share the code you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to simply remove everything else and count the number of remaining characters:

```
where length(regexp_replace(the_column, '[^/]', '', 'g')) <= 3
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4f537a55543f5971abcb9c36e4a4ebf0)